# Bluetooth doesn't working Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, wireless, bluetooth

Bluetooth doesn't working ubuntu 14.04. It doesn't find my device phone. pleaze help me!

p/s: my english bad

### Infomation:

lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c17 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0458:0152 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hu
```

lspci -nn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a06] (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9c45] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:9c03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5289] (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0f)
```

rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

thank all, pleaze :(

Answer (score 0):

from the output you provided here, your Bluetooth device is:

> Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp.

If you search with `04ca:300b` on [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net), you could find several expired bug report for this:

- [Bluetooth 04ca 300b not working Ubuntu 12.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1301721)
- [[Acer Aspire V5-132] Bluetooth not working](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1330083)

And unfortunately, it's not working in Precice and Trusty

I will suggest you to open a bug on [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net) with `ubuntu-bug linux` command in your terminal to get it fixed in future Ubuntu releases.

For more detail regrading filing bugs, you could follow this article: [ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), or this guide: [how-do-i-report-a-bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Not an easy task, but that's how we make it better, good luck!